# Creating a date column based on two different conditions

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a column that calculates the current time a person has been active on a therapy.

I have a start date column and an 'end date column'; but in the 'end date column', the people who are still active have a date of 2030-12-31 00:00:00 assigned.
I have tried to change this value only to now with pd.Timestamp("now") based on the condition of being active or not being active to today.

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')

def tiempo_terapia (row):
    if row['Fecha_baja_terapia'] == no_baja:
        return row[((now - df['Fecha_instalación_terapia'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y')).round(2)]
    else:
        return row[((df['Fecha_baja_terapia'] - df['Fecha_instalación_terapia'])/np.timedelta64(1,'Y')).round(2)]

df['Tiempo_con_terapia']= df.apply(lambda row : tiempo_terapia(row), axis =1)
df.head()
```

I keep getting different error types. The latest is:
[KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([ 9.38,  9.38, 11.78, 11.78,  7.73,  7.73, 12.33, 12.33, 12.33,\n               8.01,\n              ...\n               0.11, -0.22, -0.72, -0.39, -0.39, -0.39,  0.06,  0.08,  0.15,\n               0.14],\n             dtype='float64', length=746448)] are in the [index]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxULG.png)

Any ideas ?? I have tried everthing I find as a suggestion in stackflow

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a well written first question. The only things it's critically missing are some sample data (`row = [how exactly is it?]`) and `import pandas as pd; import numpy as np` to make it reproducible and get faster good answers. Other suggestions you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Moving on, since I do not have the original row I created a sample:

```py
import pandas
import time
import numpy

one_row = {'Name':['Maria'], 
           'Date_before': [numpy.nan], 
           'Date_later': [numpy.nan], 
           'Duration': [numpy.nan]}
one_row_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(one_row)
one_row_dataframe
#     Name  Date_before  Date_later  Duration
# 0  Maria          NaN         NaN       NaN

time_before = pandas.Timestamp('now')
time.sleep(3) # delay 3 seconds
time_later = pandas.Timestamp('now')
time_difference = time_later - time_before
duration = time_difference / numpy.timedelta64(1, 's')

one_row_dataframe['Date_before'] = one_row_dataframe['Date_before'].replace([numpy.nan],  time_before)

one_row_dataframe['Date_later'] = one_row_dataframe['Date_later'].replace([numpy.nan],  time_later)

one_row_dataframe['Duration'] = one_row_dataframe['Duration'].replace([numpy.nan],  duration)

one_row_dataframe
#     Name                Date_before                 Date_later  Duration
# 0  Maria 2022-02-11 18:14:49.242946 2022-02-11 18:14:52.246801  3.003855
```

Since this works, I am certain you can figure out how you can apply it on your case with some ad-hoc data frame/column manipulation that fits your specific data set.